# which is optimized way of using JSONObject sub elements

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I have a nested JSON object and I want to access 3 values from it which is the best-optimized way to call it.

'''

```
item.put(ITEM_COUNT, order.getJSONObject("name").getString("key1"));
item.put(PRICE, order.getJSONObject("name").getLong("key2"));
item.put(ITEM_NAME,order.getJSONObject("name").getJSONObject("key3").getString("key4"));
```

'''
or I need to create a JSON object name and the i have to get each value like
JSONObject name = order.getJSONObject("name"); and use this object now

Comment: As you're duplicating the order.getJSONObject("name") part multiple times, it would certainly do no harm bringing that out into it's own variable and using that instead.

Comment: Also, before get something by key - validate that this key exists by `has(key)` method. Otherwise you'll get JSONException